# How to count the number of queries with DBIx::Class?

Tags: perl, dbix-class

I'm using [`DBIx::Class`](http://p3rl.org/DBIx::Class) in a web context and I'd like to display the number of SQL queries performed and the time they took for the rendering of a page.

Any idea about how to implement that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [the DBIx::Class cookbook](http://search.cpan.org/dist/DBIx-Class/lib/DBIx/Class/Manual/Cookbook.pod#Profiling) on the "Profiling" section for examples on how to do that.

Simply enabling profiling via the `DBIC_TRACE=1` environment variable will not do what you want, but you can sub-class `DBIx::Class::Storage::Statistics` (as per the linked cookbook example) and override `query_start` and `query_end` in a way that lets you count the SQL queries done.

The linked example is very close to what you want to achieve.